# How to probe ownership of a MetaMask derived encryption public key?

Tags: metamask, public-key, encryption

If I were to store the messages targeted to a specific encryption public key generated by MetaMask (using x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305), how could I allow the recipient to authenticate and claim the messages in its mailbox?

I've been searching all over but apparently the public key that is shared in this scenario is only a piece of the original public key, therefore, I can't derive the correct address from it (as I could authenticate the user with a signature or something).

Anyhow, if there's no way of this, what are other alternatives for sharing secrets using a web3 identity?

**Code sample**

```typescript
// recipient requests public key and shares it with sender
const metamaskEncodedPublicKey = await provider.send("eth_getEncryptionPublicKey", [account])

// sender encrypts data using recipient's public key
const encryptedData = encrypt({publicKey, data: message, version: "x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305" })

// recipient requests data decryption
const decryptedMessage = await provider.send("eth_decrypt", [encryptedData, account])
```